Slow write operation on NFS volume
I have a problem on NFS volumes that appeared two days ago. The problem seems related to write operations, with the following taking a longer time (10s of seconds) to complete :

sed -i
rm
Editing and saving in vim

With strace, I could see that sed -i can hang at rename("./sedXXXXX", ...), or that  close(4) gives -1 EIO (Input / Output error). Also, for every sed -i call (even when it works), a line NFS: nfs4_reclaim_open_state: unhandled error -13 is reported in dmesg.
Finally, the long waiting time doesn't occur every time, and the commands will "randomly" complete without problem.
The system is under CentOS 7.4, with kernel:
$ uname -r
3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64

Do you have any idea on what could be going wrong, or on how can I trace the problem more accurately ?
Thanks in advance !
EDIT
Following the advice of grawity, setting rpcdebug -m nfs -s all leads to a lot more printing in the dmesg output, in particular:
$ dmesg | grep -i error | grep -i nfs
nfs41_handle_sequence_flag_errors: "IP_OF_NFS_SERVER" (client ID 22b1f26668d8b0fc) flags=0x00000040
nfs41_sequence_process: Error 0 free the slot

I don't know if it can be relevant though...

Have you checked the NFS server's dmesg? (Is it a Linux NFS server or something else?) Do you happen to be using Kerberos authentication for NFS? Does this happen with all files in that volume or only a specific directory?

Either rpcdebug or sysctl sunrpc.{nfs,rpc}_debug=0xffff (on the client) might reveal more – my vague guesses are a) disk/filesystem issue on the server or b) something to do with file locking

Emergent behaviour? I'd be looking at the network to see if there are errors / dropped packets / resends.

The server's dmesg is not showing anything weird.

So, the problem may have been related to NFS cache issues (see Further diagnostics below).  Following this article I ended up using the arguments hard,async,tcp on the client /etc/fstab and sync on the server /etc/exports.
Unmounting the NFS, restarting the services on the server and client, and remounting solved the problem.
Further diagnostics

When using ls or du on some directories, I had errors like
du: cannot access 'some_file_in_dir': No such file or directory


When using strace with ls I saw that the system was hanging at the getents() call, leading me to this StackOverflow post, pointing toward NFS cache problems.

